# Gorm output to json

Tags: json, go, gorp

I am trying to convert a SQL Output (GORP) to JSON. I am using [gorp](https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp) with mySql.

Here is my selected code

```
type Mane struct {
    ManeId   string `db:"mane_id"`
    Manetana string `db:"manetana"`
    Yajamana string `db:"yajamana"`
}

var manegalu []Mane
_, err = dbmap.Select(&manegalu, "SELECT mane_id, manetana, yajamana FROM kd_mane")

//Option 1: Not working: Array of numbers. Not the actual json
a, err := json.Marshal(manegalu)
mt.Fprint(w, string(a))

//Option 2: Not working: Array of numbers. Not the actual json
for _, p := range manegalu {
    a, err := json.Marshal(p)
    fmt.Fprint(w, string(a))
}
```

I am expecting and output like this

```
{"mane_id":3323, "manetana":"ABC", "yajamana":"hgy"},{"mane_id":2323, "manetana":"ADFC", "yajamana":"FDER"},{"mane_id":12343, "manetana":"GDSC", "yajamana":"hFDEy"}
```

Can you please let me know what am I doing wrong? I understand that why option 1 does not work. But option 2 seems good for me as per https://gobyexample.com/json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it done.

```
a, err := json.Marshal(manegalu) //get json byte array
n := len(a)   //Find the length of the byte array
s := string(a[:n]) //convert to string
fmt.Fprint(w, s) //write to response
```

Answer (score 2):

`json.Marshal()` returns two values, `[]byte` and `error`. You're only assigning the first in your example. See http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal.

```
a, err := json.Marshal(manegalu)
```

Edit: You'll need to convert the byte array to a string to use it with `fmt.Fprint`. In your case, `w` is an `io.Writer` interface, so you can also use:

```
w.Write(a)
```

to print the results without importing the `fmt` package. See http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer